# How to have multiple validations on injected ajax form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I would like to have a form (injected via ajax) that has multiple validations. Something like this:

```
<div data-form> <!-- Already on the page -->
  <!-- Coming from API -->
  <form> 
    <input type="number" data-input-decimal>
    <input type="number" data-input-integer>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
var $DATA_INPUT_DECIMAL = $('[data-input-decimal]');
var $DATA_INPUT_INTEGER = $('[data-input-integer]');
var $FORM = $('[data-form]');

$FORM.on('keydown', $DATA_INPUT_DECIMAL, function(e) {
  console.log('banana');
  // This is the validation for the input with decimal
}

$FORM.on('keydown', $DATA_INPUT_INTEGER, function(e) {
  console.log('apple');
  // This is the validation for the input with ONLY NUMBERS (0-9)
}
```

The weird part is when I test on the browser, both of these functions are being called when I `keydown` any of the `input`s inside the form. How do I set up different validations properly in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to achieve? Serialize custom form? Your html is not good. You can change data-input-decimal to `data-input="decimal"` and data-input-integer to `data-input="integer"` if you generate the response of ajax of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple delegation:

```js
$('[data-form]').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('[data-input-decimal]')) {
    console.log('decimal');
  } else if ($(this).is('[data-input-integer]')) {
    console.log('integer');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-form>
  <!-- Already on the page -->
  <!-- Coming from API -->
  <form>
    <input type="number" data-input-decimal>
    <input type="number" data-input-integer>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```